# Create a TableView inside a Horizontal Scrollview - Swift3, Xcode8

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uitableview, uiscrollview

I want to create a TableView inside a ScrollView but I'm not sure how to proceed.

I have a ViewController.swift that has; a navigation controller, AVFoundation methods and the horizontal scrollview (*With the tableView and tableViewCel inside it*).

The header part of my ViewControllerX file looks like this:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewControllerX: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
```

but I can't add **UITableViewController** because I already have **UIViewController**, which means I can't add the override methods for '**numberOfSections**' , '**numberOfRowsInSection**' and '**cellForRowAt indexPath**'

The Error Xcode gives me when I do add those override methods is:

> Method does not override any method from its superclass

Comment: You can add a `UITableViewController` as a *child* view controller, or you can add a `UITableView` as a subview, and implement `numberOfSections`, `numberOfRowsInSection`, etc as functions, *not* as overrides.

Comment: I haven't done either of those yet, looking at some video tutorials now it looks like that will do the trick - thank you!

Comment: @Brewski it's perfectly normal not to use a `UITableViewController`, simply remove the `override` from in front of those methods.

Comment: @paulvs Yep, that was the one that did the trick, thank you! Although I will say; I did learn in the process that it is preferred to use childviews or container views if you think you will re-use the view or if it gets too bloated, but in my case, your suggestion worked.